# Accessing a contact detail in iOS using swift

Tags: ios, nsstring, swift, abaddressbook

While using Objective-C we generally use the following code to get the details

```
NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

In Swift I tried the following

```
var firstName : NSString = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeUnretainedValue() as NSString
```

and I am not able to build because of the error

```
Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %224 = bitcast %objc_object* %223 to %PSs9AnyObject_, !dbg !486
Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %225 = bitcast %PSs9AnyObject_ %224 to i8*, !dbg !486
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works fine in Xcode6 beta 4.

```
var firstName: NSString! = Unmanaged<CFString>.fromOpaque(ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue().__conversion()
```

Answer (score 12):

This works in Xcode 6 GM

```
let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(contactRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as String
```

Slightly more concise than the above example.

Comment: How do you know it is takeRetainedValue() rather than unretained. The previous answer used unretained.

Comment: Couldn't find much information about this, but I assume you use `takeUnretainedValue()` when the pointer is to be managed by you (e.g. returned from functions with `Create` or `Copy` in their name) - this will increase their retain count by one. On the other hand you would use `takeRetainedValue()` when you work with results from methods with `Get` or similar in their name because they already have a retain count of one order to keep them alive through the life of the method.

Comment: **Update to my previous comment:** Couldn't find much information about this, but I assume you use `takeRetainedValue()` when the pointer is to be managed by you (e.g. returned from functions with `Create` or `Copy` in their name) - this will not increase their retain count by one. *On the other* hand you would use `takeUnretainedValue()` when you work with results from methods with `Get` or similar in their name because they already have a retain count of zero.